# non-graphical 3-way merge tool

Tags: rcs, three-way-merge

I currently use RCS' merge command to do 3-way merges, but one thing has always annoyed me about it. If I use the `-A` option, the same change made in both files shows up as a conflict:

```
<<<<<<< file1
file1 line 1
||||||| orig
orig line 1
=======
file2 line 1
>>>>>>> file2
orig line 2
<<<<<<< orig
=======
line added in both changes
>>>>>>> file2
orig line 3
```

If I use the default (`-E`) then those identical changes are not shown, but then the output only shows the two contributors, not the ancestor, something like this:

```
<<<<<<< file1
file1 line 1
=======
file2 line 1
>>>>>>> file2
orig line 2
line added in both changes
orig line 3
```

Is there some program that will essentially do the same behaviour as RCS merge, but has some way of showing all three versions in conflicts while automatically merging identical changes?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like diff3 has some interesting options.

On ubuntu:

```
       -m  --merge
              Output merged file instead of ed script (default -A).
```

You asked for non-graphical, but vimdiff and gvimdiff can do 3 adjacent windows.

Answer (score 1):

KDiff3 is graphical, but it does have an "--auto" option that, when called from the command line, will perform the merge and show the GUI only if a conflict occurs. I know that means you still need a GUI, but kdiff3 can still be useful from the command line. I use it that way all the time (on Windows - not sure about other versions).

(I wanted to add this comment to the other KDiff3 post, but couldn't work out how to do it - sorry.)